# Postgres can't log in to user because there isn't a system user with the same name

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm not sure if this is expected behavior of Postgres, but I'm trying to log in to a user account for my local Postgres install with:

```
sudo -u person psql
```

It prompts me for the password, which I enter, and then it says:

```
su: unknown login: person
```

When I go to list all of my Postgres users with the command `\du`, I can see the user is in this table, listed like so:

```
...
other user |   Permissions
person     |   CreateDB
other user |   Permissions
...
```

I'm using a local install of Postgres on my laptop, and there is no `person` login on this laptop. I've created `person` login only on Postgres.

**Does Postgres prevent you from logging into a user if that user does not exist on the local machine?** Not sure if that makes sense. I have Postgres installed on a remote linux server that has both a `person` linux user as well as a `person` Postgres user, and I'm not having this issue on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing the `-u` parameter to the `sudo` command, not to psql.

But you don't really need `sudo` for that to begin with.

The following should work:

```
psql -U person
```

Comment: BTW: Should be a caps `-U`

Comment: `psql -u person` didn't work for some reason, but `psql person` did. Not sure why, maybe you do? Thanks, I'll mark this correct

Comment: `psql -U person` does work, though. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @rpivovar: it should be `psql -U ...` sorry. `psql person` connects to a **database** named person using the current Linux user as the database user. That is something different than `psql -U person`

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @rpivovar: see [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) for details